# Beginner PROCESSING question about scan line and convex polygons?

Tags: processing

I am new to processing and I need some help with this algorithm.
I cannot use the fill() and line() functions.

This should draw a convex polygon ( I choose the vertexes with mouse-clicks), and when I press the "T" button it will "fill()" the polygon.

```
int x1, y1, x2, y2;

int click;

boolean scanlineOn;



void setup() {

size(640, 480);

click = 0;

scanlineOn = false;

};



void draw() {

if (click == 2) {

beoszto(x1, y1, x2, y2);

click = 0;

x1 = -1;

y1 = -1;

x2 = -1;

y2 = -1;

};

if (scanlineOn == true) {

scanline();

scanlineOn = false;

};

};



void scanline() {

int x = 1, y = 1;

int xA = -1, yA = -1;

int xB = -1;

color a;

color b;

color c;

c = get(x, y);

while (x != 639 && y != 479) {

xA = -1;

yA = -1;

xB = -1;

while (x != 639) {

a = get(x, y);

b = get(x+1, y);

if (a != b && xA == -1) {

xA = x + 1;

yA = y;

c = get(xA, yA);

} else if (c == b && a != b) {

xB = x + 1;

};

if (xA != -1 && xB != -1){

myfill(xA, yA, xB);

xA = -1;

yA = -1;

xB = -1;

};

x = x + 1;

};

y = y + 1;

x = 1;

};

};



void myfill(int xA, int yA, int xB) {

while (xA < xB) {

point(xA, yA);

xA = xA + 1;

};

};



void beoszto(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

if (x1 < x2) {

sectiondraw(x2, y2, x1, y1);

} else if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {

point(x1, y1);

} else {

sectiondraw(x1, y1, x2, y2);

};

};



void sectiondraw(int xA, int yA, int xB, int yB) {

int a, b, d, dE, dNE, a2, b2;



if (yA - yB <= 0) {

a2 = yB - yA;

} else {

a2 = yA - yB;

};

if (xA - xB <= 0) {

b2 = xB - xA;

} else {

b2 = xA - xB;

};

if (b2 >= a2) {

b = -b2;

a = a2;

} else {

b = -a2;

a = b2;

};



d = 2 * a + b;

dE = 2 * a;

dNE = 2 * (a + b);

point(xB, yB);

if (b2 >= a2 && yA >= yB) {

while (xB < xA) {

if (d >= 0) {

d = d - dE;

xB = xB + 1;

} else {

d = d - dNE;

yB = yB + 1;

xB = xB + 1;

};

point(xB, yB);

};

} else if (b2 >= a2 && yA < yB) {

while (xB < xA) {

if (d >= 0) {

d = d - dE;

xB = xB + 1;

} else {

d = d - dNE;

yB = yB - 1;

xB = xB + 1;

};

point(xB, yB);

};

} else if (b2 <= a2 && yA <= yB) {

while (yB > yA) {

if (d >= 0) {

d = d - dE;

yB = yB - 1;

} else {

d = d - dNE;

yB = yB - 1;

xB = xB + 1;

};

point(xB, yB);

};

} else {

while (yB < yA) {

if (d >= 0) {

d = d - dE;

yB = yB + 1;

} else {

d = d - dNE;

yB = yB + 1;

xB = xB + 1;

};

point(xB, yB);

};

};

};

void mousePressed() {

if (click == 0) {

x1 = mouseX;

y1 = mouseY;

click = 1;

} else {

x2 = mouseX;

y2 = mouseY;

click= 2;

};

};



void keyPressed() {

if (key == 't' || key == 'T') {

scanlineOn = true;

};

};
```

It is buggy like hell. My greatest problem is that I have to draw the polygon with multiple lines.

Comment: Please, tell us what is exactly the current behavior (what is wrong) and what is exactly expected. What is happening with the mentioned methods, fill and line? And How are you running the code?

Comment: The current behavior is :
First click= first point coordinate.
Second click = second point coordinate.

Then it will draw a line between the 2 points. 

So if i want to make a triangle i have to make 6 clicks.

Expected behavior:
First click = first point coordinate
Second click: = second point coordinate

It will draw a line.
Then It would use the previous coordinate as a starting one.
Third click= it will draw a new line between click 2 and click 3.

Comment: I am confused why you can't use the line() functions. Is there any particular reason? If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, they would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about how you would do this with `line()` and/or `fill()`, then think about how to make your own functions for `line()` and `fill()`.

Here's a hint: use an array to save the points you have clicked so far. One way to do that is like this:

```java
int count = 0;
PVector[] vertices = new PVector[1000];

void mouseClicked() {
  vertices[count] = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  count++;
}
```

Some formatting to keep in mind: in most (almost all) cases, you don't need a semicolon after a closed curly bracket. Whenever you have a semicolon inside the curly brackets, you don't need one afterward.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use the line() function you could make it like this:

```
//Create a list of all the clicked locations
ArrayList<PVector> clicked = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup(){
  size(640, 480);
}


void draw(){
  if(clicked.size() > 1){
    for (int i = 1; i < clicked.size(); i++) {
      //Draw a line between each clicked point
      line(clicked.get(i).x,clicked.get(i).y,clicked.get(i-1).x,clicked.get(i-1).y);
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  //Add new mouse presses to the list
  clicked.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}
```

Otherwise to not use the line() function you could create your own

```
void newLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
  float d = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  float m1 = (y2-y1)/d;
  float m2 = (x2-x1)/d;
  for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
    point(x1+i*m2, y1+i*m1);
  }
}
```